# how to split up a string and put each character into array in c?

Tags: c, arrays, string

which method c do this? thanks

for example, a `string [] = "abc";`

a `array[4];`

```
array[0] = 'a';
array[1] = 'b';
array[2] = 'c';
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just subscript it...

```
int main() {

  char *str = "hello";

  printf("%c", str[0]); // h

  return 0;
}
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/pAj74azc).

[You can also use array syntax](http://codepad.org/QxOjdMgD) to define the string `char str[] = "hello"`.

### Update

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

  char str[] = "hello";
  int i;
  int strLength = strlen(str);

  for (i = 0; i < strLength; i++) {

      printf("[%c]", str[i]);

  }

  return 0;
}
```

#### Output

```
[h][e][l][l][o]
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/9FO7ErP4).

Comment: `#import`? ?? And you need to `#include <stdio.h>` too for `printf` prototype.

Comment: @pmg Whoops, been a while since I used C. Will revise, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A string in C is actually an array of characters so you don't have to do anything.

retrieve it like so

```
char *string = "abcdef";
for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
    printf("%c\n", string[i]);
}
```

Comment: There's no C++ tag here so please don't post C++ code as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
char variable[] = "abc";
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the function memcpy.

Answer (score 0):

In C you don't have any specific type for string. String is a char * and points to the start of the string. Each string ends with a null character. So, you can directly use your string (char *) variable as an array but stop one character short of its strlen

Answer (score 0):

A string in C is itself an array use the following:

char yourarray[] = "asldkjsl";

each character is an array you can access them as yourarray[0], yourarray[1]